# firing a script when table datetime passes now()

Tags: mysql, database, sqlalchemy, relational-database

Im removed from Databases and are trying to get back into it somewhat.  I remember long ago creating an EBAY like app where you could create an auction with end date, and when the date passed, it would be closed.  If i recall there were 2 properties.

I am trying to create something somewhat similar. A user will define a datetime, and when that date occurs, it would fire a python script.  I dont think that it could necessarily fire scripts, but a decent alternative would be like:  if datetime <= now(), insert into outbound_requests;

I am trying to remember the keyword.

Ideally i was thinking to let the database handle all the lifting and then as now() surpasses the table's datetime column, it would execute a python script before deleting itself.

As an alternative, I could move the entry to another table for processing.

I didnt think it was a trigger, because that seems to imply an entry of sorts being inserted into the database.  I was thinking of just some sort of passive function which checked on table constraints.

All of my Code is in python, but was open to free DBMS, but was leaning towards MySQL or SQLAlchemy

I know that for my simple proof of concept, I would have a table akin to:

```
USER_ID varchar(60)
URL varchar(250)
COMMENT varchar(1000)
SUBMISSION_DATE datetime
PROCESS_DATE datetime
```

Comment: You may be thinking of [`event`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html), but it is not really the right place to execute code outside of the database. The usual place to do this is a [`cronjob`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). If you want to manage your tasks in the database, you would probably run a cronjob every x seconds that runs a script that checks (in the database) if some task is due and then execute it (from the script). In an app (that keeps running), you would do basically the same using any form of timer.

Comment: I was thinking that to keep the database encapsulated, that I could create an Event or trigger of sorts which will when the  *PROCESS_DATE* has come, to shift the entry to a different table.  For a use case, if you are familiar with the RemindMe bot on Reddit, I was dabbling with something like that, but far more scalable and efficient.  That code continually scans the DB with a Query to check datetimes, but is too process heavy and if blown up scalewise, it is not sustainable.  That way, I could create a loop which monitors a smaller table

Comment: While I do not know that bot, you describe exactly what MySQL would have to do internally if it would provide such a feature: it would basically had to continously check every row in every table. As an improvement, MySQL could however add a table with an index on a date column (basically: ordered by time), and add all events there; then it would scan the first row, and if date <= now, execute the event and delete the row and test the next one. If date > now, it can stop; since its ordered by date, all rows after that have date > now. Coming to think of it, an app could do exactly that too.

Comment: A DBMS is usually more efficient when let to accomplish tasks internally as opposed to an external resource locking it while cursors monitor things.  I remember something similar in Oracle where there was a nice optimization technique, i forget it, since i am withdrawn from Oracle.  That being said, yes you could index on completion dates. Im thinking you could create a view which would show that information, which could then be looped, and then deleted / added to a backup disc for monitoring use.

Comment: @Solarflare I think that might be a sufficient answer.  If you can create an example table, given table above, but with indexes, and a view to appropriately get that information, I feel it justifies a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussions, it was noted that to make it fast, use an index on the process date.  That way the table can iterate quickly.  Secondly, i found it smart to create a view to get the information I needed to process which leverages the index.

```
create table if not exists T(
  USER_ID nvarchar(60),
  URL nvarchar(250),
  CONTENT nvarchar(700),
  SUBMISSION_DATE datetime,
  PROCESS_DATE datetime,
  index PROCESS_DATE_IDX using BTREE (PROCESS_DATE)
);

create or replace view T_Vw as SELECT * FROM T where PROCESS_DATE < now();
```

Depending on the use of already viewed columns, it may be smart to dump old entries into a storage Table.

```
create table if not exists T_BK(
  USER_ID nvarchar(60),
  URL nvarchar(250),
  CONTENT nvarchar(700),
  SUBMISSION_DATE datetime,
  PROCESS_DATE datetime,
  index PROCESS_DATE_IDX using BTREE (PROCESS_DATE)
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER T_tgr BEFORE DELETE ON Tweet FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   insert into T_BK ('USER_ID', 'URL', 'CONTENT', 'SUBMISSION_DATE', 'PROCESS_DATE') values (OLD.USER_ID, OLD.URL, OLD.CONTENT, OLD.SUBMISSION_DATE, OLD.PROCESS_DATE);
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```